# SQL SERVER - Use CASE in WHERE statement including the column

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have this table:

```
tbl_EmpID
------------------
|EmployeeID|Group|
|----------+-----|
|100000001 |A    |
|100000002 |B    |
|100000003 |A    |
|100000004 |A    |
|100000005 |B    |
------------------
```

Now I want to create a Stored Procedure with two paramaters: @EmpFilter, @EmpList

The objective is to filter Employee based on the following:

```
'All' - Show all clients
'Group A' - Show all clients in Group A
'Group B' - Show all clients in Group B
'Specific Clients' - Show specific clients from a list regardless if Group A or B
```

I have currently this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_EmpID
WHERE [Group] = CASE @EmpFilter
                WHEN 'All' THEN [Group]
                WHEN 'Group A' THEN 'A'
                WHEN 'Group B' THEN 'B'
                END
```

and it works well. But How can the 4th option (Specific Clients) be achived?

```
Problem 1: The CASE STATEMENT is  in [Group] column. It should be filtered based on the EmployeeID
Problem 2: Should not be "=".  How can I use the WHERE IN statement in filtering EmployeeID
Problem 3: The list of specific employees will be passed to the 2nd parameter (@EmpList) which is a single line string sparated by a semicolon. 
       Example: "100000001;100000003;100000004"
```

Please help me to solve these problems.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a side note. . .setting up your stored procedure in this way is not very efficient. What happens when Group C gets added and then D. It does not make sense to have to hardcode the values in the sp each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **XML** and one more **CASE WHEN**:

```
DECLARE @EmpFilter varchar(max) = 'Specific Clients', 
        @EmpList varchar(max) = '100000001;100000003;100000005',
        @x xml

SELECT @x = CAST('<e>'+REPLACE(@EmpList,';','</e><e>')+'</e>' as xml)

SELECT e.*
FROM tbl_EmpID e
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT t.c.value('.','int') as EmployeeID
        FROM @x.nodes('/e') as t(c)
        where EmployeeID = t.c.value('.','int')
    ) as el 
WHERE [Group] = CASE @EmpFilter
                WHEN 'Specific Clients' THEN [Group]
                WHEN 'All' THEN [Group]
                WHEN 'Group A' THEN 'A'
                WHEN 'Group B' THEN 'B'
                END
    AND el.EmployeeID = CASE @EmpList 
                            WHEN NULL THEN NULL
                            ELSE e.EmployeeID END
```

For example, the above query will return:

```
EmployeeID  Group
----------- -----
100000001   A
100000003   A
100000005   B
```

Comment: The error says the Employee number value overflowed an int column.  So I changed the int to varchar and nothing's being returned. Please help :(

Comment: What is the type of `EmployeeID` column? Use the same datatype instead of `int`.

Comment: I use varchar and it needs to be varchar because there are employee ID's that have Alphabets on it. like 1000AA3

Comment: The size of `varchar` column? You need to change both `t.c.value('.','int')` to `t.c.value('.','varchar(size_here)')`

Comment: ahh yeah. it works now. thanks for that. BUT still now working well because the All doesnt retrieve all employees. just the employees on the list

Comment: Never mind the later concern, it works now. I modified the WHERE clause. Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF condition to achieve that using dynamic SQL as below

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SQL varchar(600)

SET @SQL = 
'IF (@EmpFilter != '''Specific Clients''') THEN
   SELECT * FROM tbl_EmpID
   WHERE [Group] = CASE @EmpFilter
        WHEN '''All''' THEN [Group]
        WHEN '''Group A''' THEN '''A'''
        WHEN '''Group B''' THEN '''B'''
        END;
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM tbl_EmpID
   WHERE EmployeeId IN (' + @EmpList +');
END IF';
EXEC(@SQL);
```

Please note that it is not tested as I don't have SQL server at the moment and sqlfiddle.com is broken for me as of now.

Comment: I quite sure that `EmployeeId IN (@EmpList)` doesn't work.

Comment: It will surely work if you use dynamic sql. For example checkout this link http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm

Comment: I know it works on dynamic sql. But yours isn't dynamic sql

Comment: :) Wait, I am posting the edited answer. Not tested though but give some good idea for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As my understand, when `@EmpFilter = Specific Clients`, you want to filter by `@EmpList`

You could use `charindex` to filter `EmployeeId` like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_EmpID
WHERE [Group] = CASE @EmpFilter
            WHEN 'Group A' THEN 'A'
            WHEN 'Group B' THEN 'B'                
            WHEN 'All' then [Group]
            END
    OR (      [Group] = 'Specific Clients'
         AND  Charindex(';'+ CAST(EmployeeID AS varchar(15)) + ';', ';'+ @EmpList + ';') > 0  
       )
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this logic, and it works but it takes too long to finish the execution in my real queries. Hence, the program gets error due to Timeout.

Comment: Do you have any indexes in your table? I think you coud do `IF... ELSE` as @pankaj kumar singh suggested. And read https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ for parameter sniffing problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use below stored procedure to get you result.

```
/*
    t3process 'a','by group'
    t3process 'all','all'
    t3process '100000001 ','by client'
*/

create proc t3process
(
    @EmpFilter nvarchar(100),
    @EmpList nvarchar(100)
)
as begin

if (@EmpFilter='all' and @EmpList='all')
begin
select * from t3
end 

else if(@EmpList='by group')
begin
select * from t3 where empgroup=@EmpFilter
end

else if(@EmpList='by client')
begin
select * from t3 where employeeid=@EmpFilter
end 

end
```

**Please let me know if you not getting result.**

Answer (score 0):

-- Try the code below it may helps you

```
DECLARE @EmpFilter VARCHAR(100) = 'Group A'--Specific Clients
        ,@EmpList VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @EmpList = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ';' + CAST(EmployeeID AS VARCHAR(30))
            FROM tbl_EmpID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @EmpList AS SepartedEmpList;

DECLARE @CommaintoRow TABLE (
    ID VARCHAR(100)
    ,Val VARCHAR(100)
    ,Seq INT
    );

INSERT INTO @COmmaintoRow (ID,Val)
SELECT OtherID
    ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS OtherID
        ,CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(@EmpList, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
    FROM tbl_EmpID
    ) AS A
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/M') AS Split(a);

IF @EmpFilter != 'Specific Clients'
BEGIN
    SELECT EmployeeID,[Group]
    FROM tbl_EmpID
    WHERE [Group] = (
            CASE @EmpFilter WHEN 'Group A' THEN 'A'
                WHEN 'Group B'  THEN 'B'
                WHEN 'All' THEN [Group]
                END
            )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tbl_EmpID WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT CAST(Val AS INT)FROM @COmmaintoRow
                                                        WHERE id = 1)
END
```